# How to add a new ImagestreamTag imported from dockerhub/dockerio to existing Imagestream?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3, okd

I have an Imagestream which has a tag which is imported an image from dockerio.

I want to create a template for tile38 and add a parameter for it's version. So, I want to create the imagestreamTag and pull the corresponding image from dockerio if that specific version imagestreamTag doesn't exist.

Is there anyway to do so?

P.S: I use openshift origin v3.10